# Listing images in unknown number of subdirectories

Tags: image

How can I list my JPEG images while I do not know the name of each sub directory and number of sub directories? (See blow mapping for clarification)

```
MyDIR
   Unknown sub DIR
         Unknown sub sub DIR
                Unknown sub sub sub DIR
                  .
                  .
                  .
                       1.jpg
                       2.jpg
```

Thanks!

Comment: What OS ? What language ? What do you mean by "reading" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but if you want to list .jpg files on Linux, you can do it that way :

```
find *directory* -type f -name "*.extension*"
```

For example, for JPEG files inside */opt/*

```
find /opt/ -type f -name "*.jpg"
```

> ...
>
> /opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/share/doc/tiff-4.0.6/html/images/bali.jpg
>
> /opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.6.2-4/doc/global/template/images/Qt-header-bg.jpg
>
> /opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.6.2-4/doc/global/template/images/Qt-footer-bg.jpg
>
> ...

Comment: I mean I have a parent directory and I know its name. Inside this parent directory, there is one subdirectory, but I do not know its name. Inside the latter directory, there is a sub directory (I do not know its name too). Inside this directory, there is a sub directory again (I do not know its name too). I do not know when this ring finishes but I know that at the end of these sub sub sub sub ... sub directories I have my jpg images.

Comment: @Hossein This is exactly what my solution does above, but just list them. So, now, what do you mean by "reading"?

Comment: I just wanted to list them. Thanks!